# In Java What is the exit value of a process which is killed in the background through Linux shell using process id

Tags: java, linux

Using Java, I am executing a process in linux environment like below

```
Process startPingProcess = Runtime.getRuntime()().exec(ping -c 50 74.125.228.71);
```

we check whether process has completed its execution using `startPingProcess.exitValue()` in java, it will `return 0` if completed normally.

Suppose if I'm killing the above started process in the middle by executing below code

```
Runtime.getRuntime()().exec(kill -2 processid); - where processid is process id of above started process
```

What is `exitValue` of `startPingProcess` object?

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Java specific question. The return code will be the same for all Unix systems here (at least I have never seen a Unix system *not* behaving this way): 128 + the number of the signal which caused the process to terminate. No idea for Windows...

Therefore, 130 in your case. In C, you'd check (after a call to `waitpid()` for instance) whether a process has been terminated by a signal using `WIFSIGNALED(status)`.